# Unable to remove azure group from repository

Tags: azure-devops, azure-security

I'm having issues removing a group from repository permission list group. I can explain my case with the next sample:

**1. I created two groups: Team A and Team B:**

[image]
 **2. A new repo was created, then i added one of the groups to the Repos root, and i assigned all the permissions to this group.**

[image]

**3. Then, checking the new repo ("Test"), this has the group in the list too, normal behavior if you have the inheritance turned on.**

[image]

**Now the issue happens when i try to remove the group from the child repository ("Test"). Azure shows the next error: "Team A has inherited permissions and cannot be removed from the list.". Even i tried to remove with the inheritance disabled, but without success.**

[image]

**Someone can explain me why is happening this? Or what i can do to remove the group from the child repository.**

Comment: May I know how's the status of this? Does below explanation is help for you? Did you still has any puzzle or question on that? If it help, appreciate for [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) thus other SO users will be able to see whether the it is works.

Answer (score 1):

This should be the expected action which is by designed.

In step2, you add the group in the **top-level** repositories. This is the action which will make changes to all repositories. When the sub-repos enabled the **Inheritance**, the child individual repos will inherit the permissions from top-level **automatically**.

This was mentioned in this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/permissions?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page#git-repository-object-level):

> Set permissions across all Git repositories by making changes to the
>   top-level Git repositories entry.
>
> Individual repositories inherit permissions from the top-level Git
>   Repositories entry. Branches inherit permissions from assignments made
>   at the repository level.

For more detailed, you add `Team A`, `Team B` into the top-level repositories, and you make the `Inheritance` as `true` in sub-repos.

At this time, the system will reject your request with the message *({group} has inherited permissions and cannot be removed from the list)* when you trying to remove `Team A` from one child repo. Because this `Team A` still keep the permission occupation in other sub-repos in the meanwhile.

> Or what i can do to remove the group from the child repository.

I'm afraid this could not be achieved, because this is the security model limitation. Every permission group has its corresponding security model. In this `Version Control Administration` panel, the rules of this model does not allow the Users or Groups which added into the top-level repository and be inherited by child, can be removed from child.

In this scenario, you had remove them from top-level.

So, I'd suggest that you need add users/groups into top-level repositories carefully while these some groups/users need a global permission. Most of scenarios, add for individual repos would much better. Of course, this based on the actual demands of groups/users.

Comment: even removing from the top level prevented removing a group from a child node...it will get messy very quickly